# Install Ubuntu 18.04 with latest kernel

Tags: drivers, 18.04, kernel, iso, motherboard

After changing some PC pieces (most importantly MOBO), my Ubuntu started not working correctly e.g. no ethernet. After updating the Kernel to the latest one, the ethernet worked again but audio are still an issue. I would like to reinstall Ubuntu 18.04 just to try again fresh, but I already have problems because the ISO Kernel is outdated for my MOBO (ASUS TUF GAMING B550M PLUS).

Is there a way to install 18.04 with an updated kernel? I need specific packages from 18.04.

Comment: Why such fixation on a release older than your hardware?

Comment: my company code only works on specific packages versions from 18.04 :/

Comment: Install Ubuntu 20.04 (or 21.04 in case 20.04's kernel does not support the hardware). Then run 18.04 specific code in virtualbox.

Comment: virtualbox doesn't really work well because it's cpu intensive software, but it would be a solution yes. I want to try installing a newer ubuntu and downgrading the specific packages, do you think that's possible to work?

Comment: No, downgrading software requires a lot of effort in general. However, if your code needs an older version of Python or C compiler, that can be easily installed in a later version of Ubuntu. You can ask a new question about it (mention exactly which all development packages you need).

Comment: Ubuntu LTS releases come with two kernel stack choices; you've made no mention of whether or not you're using the GA stack or HWE.  Please provide specific details (if you're using the GA for example; just switching to HWE gives you a much newer kernel; ie. a two year jump).

Comment: sorry, I did not know that. HWE could very well solve my problem.Thank you very much I will look into it!